# creating implicit type class instance in generic way for Seq collections

Tags: scala, typeclass, implicit

I'm trying to write a generic implicit instance for the following structure :

```
      object SmartHasher {
    
       trait GetSmartHash[T] {
          def calculateHash(value: T): Int
        }
    
        object syntax {
          implicit class GetHashOps[T: GetSmartHash](itemToBeHashed: T) {
            def hashItSmartway(implicit GetSmartHashInstance: GetSmartHash[T]): Int =
              GetSmartHashInstance.calculateHash(itemToBeHashed)
          }
    }

 object instances {
      import syntax._
     
     implicit def stringSmartHash: GetSmartHash[String] = (s: String) =>s.size % 10 // smart demo thing :D
     
}
```

Now I'm trying to define a generic implicit instance that works for any Vector, List, Or Array

where smarthash method for its elements are defined
:

*What type I shoud use instead of Seq ,  as Im trying with it and it doesnt work out ?*

```
implicit def sequenceHash[T: GetSmartHash]: GetSmartHash[Seq[T]] =
        (sequence: Seq[T]) => sequence.map(element => element.hashItSmartway).product
```

If I define  It for an exact collection like Vector :

```
 implicit def sequenceHash[T: GetSmartHash]: GetSmartHash[Vector[T]] =
            (sequence: Vector[T]) => sequence.map(element => element.hashItSmartway).product
```

then it works as I expected.
Any suggestions to write this in generic way for theese 3 collections, to prevent for repeating simillar code 3 times?
Regards.

Comment: *"What type I shoud use instead of `Seq`, as Im trying with it and it doesnt work out ?"* What do you mean by "not working out"? *"If I define It for an exact collection like Vector : ... then it works as I expected."* What do you mean by "working as expected"? Provide details about desired behaviour and current issues.

Comment: It compiles And runs , If I Use Seq  then  im getting  compilation error: value hashItSmartway is not a member of scala.collection.immutable.Vector  I think the compiler doesn't catch signature with Seq when is in input Vector or List

Comment: BTW, you may want to make your implicit class also a value class to avoid instantiation for the extension methods.

Answer (score 2):

Try

```
object instances {
  import syntax._

  // stringSmartHash ...
   
  implicit def sequenceHash[Col[X] <: Iterable[X], T: GetSmartHash]: GetSmartHash[Col[T]] =
    (sequence: Col[T]) => sequence.map(element => element.hashItSmartway).product
}
```

Testing:

```
import instances._, syntax._
List("aa", "bbb").hashItSmartway //6
Seq("aa", "bbb").hashItSmartway //6
Vector("aa", "bbb").hashItSmartway //6
```

If you want `sequenceHash` to work also for `Array` replace upper bound with view bound

```
implicit def sequenceHash[Col[_], T: GetSmartHash](implicit ev: Col[T] => Iterable[T]): GetSmartHash[Col[T]] =
  (sequence: Col[T]) => sequence.map(element => element.hashItSmartway).product
```